# Output running python script with PHP. Exec, passthru and system gives error "could not find terminal"

Tags: php, python, terminal, output

I'm trying to run python script from php as normal with exec, but it gives:

```
curses.wrapper(curses_loop) [5]
     => File "/opt/python27/lib/python2.7/curses/wrapper.py", line 22, in wrapper [6] 
     => stdscr = curses.initscr() [7] 
     => File "/opt/python27/lib/python2.7/curses/__init__.py", line 33, in initscr [8] 
     => fd=_sys.__stdout__.fileno()) [9] 
     => _curses.error: setupterm: could not find terminal
```

The python script is a program that works fine in terminal. It is a program for currency charts, forex and etc with many options.
I think that the problem is that the program uses the terminal to work properly and can't simulate this on output(stdout and etc).

Also I tried to update wrapper.py as [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue5622), but failed. The error occurs again.

Also I tried, in terminal `export TERM=xterm-new` or `export TERM=xterm-256color`, but failed again.

I'm stuck, please help if you can and if it is possible.

Comment: This is the part of the code from my python script: 'if secret.prompt_decrypt() != secret.S_FAIL_FATAL: curses.wrapper(curses_loop)'. This is the part of the php code that runs the python script: 'exec("python myscript.py 2>&1", $some_var);'.

Comment: Well, presumably your PHP script is running from a webserver, and a webserver doesn't usually have a controlling tty, so you can't (easily) spawn a curses-based process from it. What is it you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: @PbB Have you tried to use `system`, `shell_exec` or `passthru` (with full paths)?

Comment: Thank you for helping me. Mr. Salem, I tried with 'system','shell_exec' and 'passthru' with full paths, and no success. There is no output at all, nothing. I want to give a little description of my python script-program. It's not a little script that has only output something like "hello world". When it's start, it is a system for currency trading. It has a screen to see charts, it has keyboard shortcuts, it has login and so on. So, I think I need to change my question, is it possible to output this to the browser with all functionality. I think this answer your question Aya :)

Comment: Also I tried with python subprocess                                 'sub #!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import sys
child = subprocess.Popen("python ~/full path to my script/myscript.py", shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
    out = child.stderr.read(1)
    if out == '' and child.poll() != None:
        break
    if out != '':
        sys.stdout.write(out)
        sys.stdout.flush()'                                           And the error is the same: '_curses.error: setupterm: could not find terminal'

Comment: Well, you might be able to remote-control a curses-based app by creating a new controlling tty, but rendering the output to a browser will be very complicated - you'd probably have to write a custom implementation of Python's `curses` library. It may be quicker just to rewrite the application from scratch.

Comment: Thank you for your help Aya. I will try to make something and will give you feedback. :) Thank you all.